# looking for help in understanding different codes functions

Tags: excel, vba

i am trying to create a formula to detect two things.
1- detect number of cells set high (have a value of 1) in each row and pop up msg when 7 column in a raw were high. and then go to the next raw till all rows finished.
2- extract  this high input from another document (word) based on title.

have been struggling with identifying the cells and doing the 7 in a raw calculation. mostly because of faults like out of range.

```
Sub SplitByPerson()

  Dim ColDestCrnt As Long
  Dim ColDestTitle As Long
  Dim ColSrc As Long
  Dim RowSrcCrnt As Long
  Dim RowSrcSt As Long
  Dim RowSrcStartCycle As Long
  Dim RowDestCrnt As Long
  Dim sickCrnt As Long
  Dim sickTotal As Long
  Dim sickcount As Long

  Dim MyArray() As Integer
  MyArray(8) = 234 ' Causes Error 9.

  ' Assume data starts in B3
  RowSrcSt = 3
  ColSrc = 2

  ' Detection cycles starting from Row 3
  'RowDestCrnt = 3
 ' ColDestTitle = 1

  'With Worksheets("Sheet1")



    Do Until RowSrcCrnt = 20

    If RowSrcCrnt < 20 And ColSrc < 20 Then
      ' Record start of sick cycle

      RowSrcCrnt = RowSrcSt + 1

      ' Search for sick for 7 days
      Do Until RowSrcCrnt = 20 & ColSrc = 20

        RowSrcCrnt = RowSrcCrnt
        ColSrc = ColSrc + 1

        If Sheet1.Cells(RowSrcCrnt, ColSrc).Value > 0 And _
        Range("RowSrcCrnt").Formula.Value = "=SUM (" & Range(Cells("RowSrcCrnt", "ColSrc"), Cells("RowSrcCrnt", "ColSrc" + 6)).Address(False, False) & ")" > 7 Then

        'The two false after Adress is to define the vaddress as relative (A2:B3).
        'If you omit the parenthesis clause or write True instead, you can set the address
        'as absolute ($A$2:$B$3)._

        ' This shows it have been sick for 7 weeks
        MsgBox " 7 sick weeks reached for " & Range(Cells(RowSrcCrnt, 1)).Value


          Exit Do
        End If
        ' Continue search for 7 weeks abscense
      Loop

        Exit Do
      End If

   Loop
           MsgBox " Search finished "

 End With

End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhBLs.png)

Comment: show your code and your data mockup

Comment: It's not clear what you mean when you're saying seven in a row. Do you mean 7 consecutive high values or 7 high values in total in each row?

Comment: Hi,i want to detect consecutive occurrence of having value (1) in columns on each row.

Comment: @Shadz Could you please update your original post and add the code there? It's not readable in the comment.

Comment: @StavrosJon thanks for the tip, quite new around, have updated the original post with the code that keep giving me out of range. also a print screen of the excel example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
Sub consecutiveSevens()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim rngRow As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim maxCon As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
Set rng = sht.Range("A1:Z10")

For Each rngRow In rng.Rows
    i = 0
    maxCon = 0
    For Each cell In rngRow.Cells
        If cell.Value = 1 Then
            i = i + 1
            If i > maxCon Then
                maxCon = i
            End If
        Else
            If i > maxCon Then
                maxCon = i
            End If
            i = 0
        End If
    Next cell
    If maxCon > 7 Then
        rngRow.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 200, 0)
        MsgBox "More than 7 consecutive 1's were found in row: " & rngRow.row
    Else
        rngRow.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 200, 200)
    End If
Next rngRow

End Sub
```

The code tracks the maximum consecutive occurrences of 1 in each row. If they are more than 7 the row is highlighted in green color and a message pops up. If not then the row is highlighted in pink.

Here's a sample:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, yet this is not what i am looking for, i am not trying to detect the sum of each row, i am trying to detect the when seven consecutive occurrences ( in our case 7 ones in a raw) on each row, and when the row column limit is reached go the next row. till the end of the range. and then have a pop up with person 1,2,3 ..  have had this occurrence for x number of times.
my code keep getting out of range even though i have created some limits.
have tried your coloring thing but it is also giving out of range!

Comment: I am not detecting the sum...I am detecting consecutive occurences. If The maximum consecutive occurences are more than 7 then the row turns green. Then the code moves on to the next row. Did you read my answer? I am doing exactly what you described in the code above. Please read it carefully.

Comment: apology, i have renamed the sheet and that was the reason why i  am getting the out of range error. this is what i was looking for. much appreciated.